# MySQL datetime NULL issue, '=' and '!=' return 0 rows

Tags: java, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a table `linksbase` that is filled with values. `lastvisited` is datetime and is NULL everywhere (nulls are allowed). I run query in phpmyadmin (same via Java) and go empty result:

```
SELECT `id` FROM `linksbase` WHERE `lastvisited` = NULL
```

What's more, if I run

```
SELECT `id` FROM `linksbase` WHERE `lastvisited` != NULL
```

I also get emplty result.
If I run

> SELECT * FROM `linksbase` WHERE 1

I get a list of rows like should be (so, it's working).

What's wrong with the query and why two mutually excluding queries return 0 rows.

Comment: Have you tried with  `IS` like `WHERE lastvisited IS NULL` , `WHERE lastvisited IS NOT NULL`

Comment: NULL is neither equal nor not equal to anything. Not even NULL!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use

```
SELECT `id` FROM `linksbase` WHERE `lastvisited` IS NULL
```

and

```
SELECT `id` FROM `linksbase` WHERE `lastvisited` IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: @Tigran [3.3.4.6 Working with NULL Values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html) Because the result of any arithmetic comparison with NULL is also NULL, you cannot obtain any meaningful results from such comparisons.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan they allowed check my answer

Answer (score 3):

You should be using `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL` instead of comparing NULL with `!` or `!=` operators.  Those will always be false.

Answer (score 0):

if you have empty columns and not null , then consider to use this

```
 SELECT `id` FROM `linksbase` WHERE  `lastvisited` = ''  OR `lastvisited` IS NULL
```

this will look for empty columns and columns with null .